# Why does SVG produce blurry image in Firefox for large ViewBox dimensions

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I'm trying to create an infinite zoom effect with a single repeating image.To preserve image quality across different size scales, I chose to 
use SVG.

The problem is that the image is crisp when stationary in Firefox, but it becomes very blurry when the zoom interval(ms) is set to anything 100ms or less. Especially at the initial stages of the zoom.

I've tried different values for "shape-rendering" style property as well as setting preserveAspectRatio=false on the graphic.
The image stays crisp in Chrome. I don't know how to debug this.

I really appreciate any help or ideas you can offer!

Example: https://codepen.io/mannadu/pen/MMybwL

Filter

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="yinyang" width="466" height="466" viewBox="-40 -40 80 80" preserveAspectRatio="false">
                        <g id="yyyy" transform="scale(20) translate(0 21.8)">
                        <g id="yyy">
                        <g id="yy">
                        <g id="y">
                        <circle id="yinner" r="39"/>
                        <path d="M0,38a38,38 0 0 1 0,-76a19,19 0 0 1 0,38a19,19 0 0 0 0,38" fill="#fff"/>
                        <circle cy="-19" r="5"/>
                        <circle cy="19" r="5" fill="#fff"/>
                        </g>
                        <use href="#y" transform="translate(0 , -19) scale(.15)"/>
                        <use href="#y" class="gany" transform="translate(0 , 19) scale(.15)"/>
                        </g>
                        <use href="#yy" transform="translate(0 , -19) scale(.15)" />
                        <use href="#yy" class="gany" transform="translate(0 , 19) scale(.15)" />
                        </g>
                        <use href="#yyy" transform="translate(0 , -19) scale(.15)" />
                        <use href="#yyy" class="gany" transform="translate(0 , 19) scale(.15)" />
                        </g>
                </svg>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be tweening the `viewBox` properties. Instead, try wrapping all the inner content of your SVG in another `<g>` element, and animate it's `transform` property instead.

Comment: The value I was using for preserveAspectRatio should be "none" not "false" this seems to help quite a bit. Though there is still some momentary blurriness

Answer (score 4):

To further elaborate from my comment: you should not be mutating/updating the `viewBox` attribute, because then the browser has to continuously recalculate the inner scale of the SVG element. This can result in performance issues or anti-aliasing issues, such as what you're seeing in Firefox.

What you're trying to do is to simply apply yet another transform to your SVG element. The fastest, band-aid kind of way to fix it is to simply wrap the inner HTML of your SVG element in a `<g>` element:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="yinyang" width="466" height="466" viewBox="-40 -40 80 80">
  <g id="outer" transform="scale(1)">
    <!-- Original SVG content -->
  </g>
</svg>
```

Then, using JS, you can change its `transform` attribute in your interval callback:

```js
const yinyang = document.getElementById("yinyang");
const outer = document.getElementById('outer');
const scalefactor = 1.01;

let scale = 1;
const zoomyInterval = setInterval(() => {
    scale /= scalefactor;
    outer.setAttribute('transform', `scale(${scale})`);
  },
  100
);
```

See proof-of-concept here (also [forked your CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZdWBNG)):

```js
const yinyang = document.getElementById("yinyang");
const outer = document.getElementById('outer');
const scalefactor = 1.01;

let scale = 1;
const zoomyInterval = setInterval(() => {
    scale /= scalefactor;
    outer.setAttribute('transform', `scale(${scale})`);
  },
  100
);
```

```css
.gany {
  filter: invert(1);
  -webkit-filter: invert(1);
  /* Not working for svg <use> elements in Chrome */
}

svg {
  shape-rendering: geometricPresicion;
  /* 
  Attempt to address blurry rasterized image in Firfox */
}

circle {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="yinyang" width="466" height="466" viewBox="-40 -40 80 80">
  <g id="outer" transform="scale(1)">
    <g id="yyyy" transform="scale(20) translate(0 21.8)">
      <g id="yyy">
        <g id="yy">
          <g id="y">
            <circle id="yinner" r="39" />
            <path d="M0,38a38,38 0 0 1 0,-76a19,19 0 0 1 0,38a19,19 0 0 0 0,38" fill="#fff" />
            <circle cy="-19" r="5" />
            <circle cy="19" r="5" fill="#fff" />
          </g>
          <use href="#y" transform="translate(0 , -19) scale(.15)" />
          <use href="#y" class="gany" transform="translate(0 , 19) scale(.15)" />
        </g>
        <use href="#yy" transform="translate(0 , -19) scale(.15)" />
        <use href="#yy" class="gany" transform="translate(0 , 19) scale(.15)" />
      </g>
      <use href="#yyy" transform="translate(0 , -19) scale(.15)" />
      <use href="#yyy" class="gany" transform="translate(0 , 19) scale(.15)" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Even better: use `window.requstAnimationFrame()`

You will notice that even though the above example works, your animation remains choppy: that is because you are only updating the scale of the `<g>` element at 100ms intervals, which translates to a frame rate of 10fps. That movement is not going to look fluid. What you want, is to smoothly calculate the next `scale` whenever the browser is repainting.

If we lightly refactor your resizing logic, you have something like this:

```
const yinyang = document.getElementById("yinyang");
const outer = document.getElementById('outer');
const scalefactor = 1.01;
let scale = 1;

let start = null;
const zoomStep = (timestamp) => {
  if (!start) {
    start = timestamp;
  }
  
  const progress = timestamp - start;
  
  // Here, we want to shrink the scale by the scalefactor by exponential transformation
  // You can change the `500` value to whatever value you want to achieve the speed you desire
  scale = scale / Math.pow(scalefactor, progress / 500);
  outer.setAttribute('transform', `scale(${scale})`);
  
  // Optional: Arbirary limit to stop animation
  if (scale > 0.01) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(zoomStep);
  }
};

window.requestAnimationFrame(zoomStep);
```

See improved proof-of-concept:

```js
const yinyang = document.getElementById("yinyang");
const outer = document.getElementById('outer');
const scalefactor = 1.01;
let scale = 1;

let start = null;
const zoomStep = (timestamp) => {
  if (!start) {
    start = timestamp;
  }
  
  const progress = timestamp - start;
  
  // Here, we want to shrink the scale by the scalefactor by exponential transformation
  // You can change the `500` value to whatever value you want to achieve the speed you desire
  scale = scale / Math.pow(scalefactor, progress / 500);
  outer.setAttribute('transform', `scale(${scale})`);
  
  // Optional: Arbirary limit to stop animation
  if (scale > 0.01) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(zoomStep);
  }
};

window.requestAnimationFrame(zoomStep);
```

```css
.gany {
  filter: invert(1);
  -webkit-filter: invert(1);
  /* Not working for svg <use> elements in Chrome */
}

svg {
  shape-rendering: geometricPresicion;
  /* 
  Attempt to address blurry rasterized image in Firfox */
}

circle {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="yinyang" width="466" height="466" viewBox="-40 -40 80 80">
  <g id="outer" transform="scale(1)">
    <g id="yyyy" transform="scale(20) translate(0 21.8)">
      <g id="yyy">
        <g id="yy">
          <g id="y">
            <circle id="yinner" r="39" />
            <path d="M0,38a38,38 0 0 1 0,-76a19,19 0 0 1 0,38a19,19 0 0 0 0,38" fill="#fff" />
            <circle cy="-19" r="5" />
            <circle cy="19" r="5" fill="#fff" />
          </g>
          <use href="#y" transform="translate(0 , -19) scale(.15)" />
          <use href="#y" class="gany" transform="translate(0 , 19) scale(.15)" />
        </g>
        <use href="#yy" transform="translate(0 , -19) scale(.15)" />
        <use href="#yy" class="gany" transform="translate(0 , 19) scale(.15)" />
      </g>
      <use href="#yyy" transform="translate(0 , -19) scale(.15)" />
      <use href="#yyy" class="gany" transform="translate(0 , 19) scale(.15)" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I considered adjusting the image transform instead also, but didn't realize how much more performant it would be.  I still get some blurriness in FF with the reworked transform, but anyway Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mannadu You're welcome! I have also updated my answer with a more modern solution, that uses `window.requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`: if you look at the improved snippet, the animation is way smoother :)

Comment: In your very first sentence ("you should be mutating/updating the viewBox attribute") – don't you mean "shouldn't"?